# Run a IO task with timeout in F#

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I am trying to talk to cloud services in F# and have timeouts around these operations.

This is now multiple iterations later but I still cannot figure out how to use Async.

```
    let tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource()
    let task        = Async.StartAsTask(async {return (getS3Meta keyMeta)}, TaskCreationOptions.None, tokenSource.Token)
    let metaMaybe   = Async.AwaitTask(task, 700) |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

To support the timeout we introduced:

```
  type Timeout = Timeout

  type Microsoft.FSharp.Control.Async with

    static member AwaitTask (t : Task<'T>, timeout : int) =
        async {
            use cts = new CancellationTokenSource()
            use timer = Task.Delay (timeout, cts.Token)
            let! completed = Async.AwaitTask <| Task.WhenAny(t, timer)
            if completed = (t :> Task) then
                cts.Cancel ()
                let! result = Async.AwaitTask t
                return Ok result
            else return Error Timeout
        }
```

Whatever I do the task is always in WaitingForActivation.

What is the recommended way of having a timeout on an IO operation, it can block the main execution, I do not need async code here. If I must use async then what is the primitive to use to start a task that has a timeout?

Comment: Why is this tagged C#?

Comment: At which point during the execution is the task in the `WaitingForActivation` state? I tested this with `Thread.Sleep` in place of your actual IO operation and I get `WaitingForActivation` state right after the `StartAsTask` call, but the task then starts (presumably whenever the scheduler picks it up from the task pool) and finishes as expected. Or do you want to avoid the scheduler somehow?

Comment: Hi @TomasPetricek I got this state after the timeout (500 - 700 ms). I am working on a project that requires a much faster response time from an async task than this. Ideally I would like to timeout on everything that takes longer than 250ms.

Comment: It seems there is an initial slow start when you create the first task. After that it gets much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The currently working code (we have not run into issues with this, even though we do not understand the different tradeoffs associated with different Async workflows).

```
  let doSomeIoAsync =
    async {
      return (anotherAsyncWokFlowIoInCsharpLib someParam)
    }

  let task = Async.StartAsTask doSomeIoAsync

  match task.Wait(500) with
   | true ->  Success task.Result
   | false -> Error Timeout
```

Some fsi:

```
> let ioFn () = Thread.Sleep(5000); System.Console.WriteLine 100; 100;;
Real: 00:00:00.000, CPU: 00:00:00.000, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
val ioFn : unit -> int

> ioFn();;
100
Real: 00:00:05.005, CPU: 00:00:00.001, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
val it : int = 100

> let taskAsync = async { return ioFn() };;
Real: 00:00:00.000, CPU: 00:00:00.000, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
val taskAsync : Async<int>

> let t = Async.StartAsTask taskAsync ;;
Real: 00:00:00.000, CPU: 00:00:00.000, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
val t : Tasks.Task<int>

> t.Wait(500) ; t.Status;;
Real: 00:00:00.505, CPU: 00:00:00.001, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
val it : Tasks.TaskStatus = WaitingForActivation

> 100

- t.Wait(500) ; t.Status;;
Real: 00:00:00.000, CPU: 00:00:00.000, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
val it : Tasks.TaskStatus = RanToCompletion

> t.Result;;
Real: 00:00:00.000, CPU: 00:00:00.000, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
val it : int = 100
```

I think it is a bit misleading that WaitingForActivation is used like this. Maybe I am misinterpreting that and it is WaitingForCompletion really.

As far as performance goes the first couple of requests are extremely slow compare to the rest:

```
Error: WaitingForActivation
Elapsed Time: 296
Error: WaitingForActivation
Elapsed Time: 254
Error: WaitingForActivation
Elapsed Time: 255
Error: WaitingForActivation
Elapsed Time: 254
Error: WaitingForActivation
Elapsed Time: 254
OK: RanToCompletion
Elapsed Time: 249
OK: RanToCompletion
Elapsed Time: 147
OK: RanToCompletion
Elapsed Time: 246
OK: RanToCompletion
Elapsed Time: 146
OK: RanToCompletion
Elapsed Time: 150
OK: RanToCompletion
Elapsed Time: 142
OK: RanToCompletion
Elapsed Time: 143
OK: RanToCompletion
Elapsed Time: 139
OK: RanToCompletion
Elapsed Time: 139
OK: RanToCompletion
Elapsed Time: 141
```

Not sure how to get rid off the slow start.